# enumerate flash externalinterface javascript

Tags: javascript, flash

It is possible in javascript or by third party flash wrapper to enumerate all flash externalinterface?

if yes, then how to do that?

what I want to do is to get all externalinterface from flash object, and find the one I need. I do not have access to flash object source code.  And I want to know if it possible and how.

Also this is not only for a single flash object, it is for any flash object in any website.
What exactly I'm trying to do is to know which commands support flash player using externalinterface to call them with javascript, or how to achieve similar task?